# NSAttributedString won't add attributes to a string. (Swift 5)

Tags: swift, string, xcode, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I'm trying to colour occurrences of a string in a string using the below:

```
let text = "R09/27 R13/51 R22/08 R11/11"
let attributed = text.color2(redText: ["R09/27", "R11/11"], orangeText: ["R13/51"])
print(attributed)
textLabel.attributedText = attributed
```

And with the following extension:

```
extension String {
    func color2(
        redText: [String],
        orangeText: [String]
    ) -> NSAttributedString {

    let result = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)
    enumerateSubstrings(in: startIndex..<endIndex, options: .byWords) {
        (substring, substringRange, _, _) in
        guard let substring = substring else { return }
        if redText.contains(substring) {
            result.addAttribute(
                .foregroundColor,
                value: UIColor.systemRed,
                range: NSRange(substringRange, in: self)
            )
        }

        if orangeText.contains(substring) {
            result.addAttribute(
                .foregroundColor,
                value: UIColor.systemOrange,
                range: NSRange(substringRange, in: self)
            )
        }
    }
    return result
}

}
```

However the string will not color. When I print the attribute in the console it doesn't show any attributes like normally but rather { }. Does anyone know why my text won't color the occurrences? I have used this code before in another app and worked fine, I can't see what is different here and why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't see what is different here and why it doesn't work.

The issue is merely that you've made this odd decision to cycle through the string *by word*. Well, forward slash is a word divider, so the words are

```
R09
27
R13
51
R22
08
R11
11
```

None of those is a match for any of your `redText` or `orangeText` strings. No match, no color.

Comment: I guess it makes sense why it works on the other app which doesn’t have a slash. What can I cycle with to include the divider or cycle with space?